# Angular model definition is replaced by web services model

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I've got a typescript model like this :

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class Activity {
  public id: number;      
  public activityDate: string;      
  public day: number = moment(this.activityDate).dayOfYear();
}
```

And a C# model sent by WebApi like this :

```
public class Activity
{     
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("activityDate")]
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }
}
```

And a mapping by a simple `response.json()` in my service class.

My issue is the property `day` disappears from my model.ts.

So, is there something that I can declare to keep integrity on typescript model ? Or any binding on model retrieve the structure too ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the property `day` disappears"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a mapping from `response.json()` call, the day property don't will be calculated automatically, here goes a suggestion:

```
export interface Activity {
  id: number;
  activityDate: string;
  day?: number;
}
export const mapActivityFromServer(d => ({
  ...d,
  day: moment(d.activityDate).dayOfYear()
}));
```

Comment: Ok, so for each custom property, i do create a manual mapping ? Is there an automapper or something like that in Angular ?

Comment: yeah, for all derived properties... IDK an automapper built in angular, I think that u need to implement yourself